# What type of safety pin would be correct for this tailgate latch?

Tags: trailer, tailgate

My utility trailer has these tailgate latches on each side:
[image]

As you can see there is a secondary safety pin which is meant to prevent the latch from opening by mistake. However this doesn't seem to be the right type of pin... its possible for it to slip too far through the hole (or be mis-installed) like this:

[image]

in which case it doesn't really serve its purpose.

I've never actually had a problem with this, but I'd feel much better if I could replace these with some other sort of pin that would avoid the problem. I'm familiar with several types of pins, some agricultural, but all seem like they would have the same problem.

Can anyone recommend a style of pin that would work here?

Answer (score 8):

Based on the search results for that specific type of latch, the "pin hole" is not a latch-opening-preventer, in the generic sense. An [Australian resource](https://www.trailercamperaustralia.com.au/ark-trailer-tailgate-latch.html) shows this exact type of latch:

[image: over center latch]

The advert copy reads

> Over center adjustable latch with padlock facility.

I suspected that it was aimed at a padlock rather than a second level of security against opening. Bicycle locks with the extended hoop would allow the lock to pass through the hole and behind the handle, preventing it from dropping out/down.

Answer (score 7):

I think a large diameter safety pin would work just fine. Something like [this](https://www.actiontrucks.com/product-detail/CUR25010/5-16in-safety-pin-3in-pin-length)

[image: trailer hitch safety pin]